# hm-10 SHIELD assistance command after first pairing

Tags: hm-10

[hm-10 shild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFc6G.jpg)

hello,

did anyone here used HM-10 SHIELD ?

i need a code that after the first pairing any time that the HM-10 SHIELD will identify my ble\phone then the HM-10 SHIELD or the arduino  will send a massage or any other command to pc or other

thanks!!!

Reg
MBK

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? What doc have you read, that does not provide you with some sort of solution?

Answer (score 0):

i am new at this tech and i am still learning but i really love to try.

So far I've connected the hm-10 to the Arduino and managed to send some basic commands to it. I'm looking for a code that will help me understand how to use it for proximity (when a device is connected or near the BT range)

thanks !
MBK